# Adding more text in the fullcalendar dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I need to display more text in the fullcalander. but the problem is i am getting data from the mySQL db as json data through ajax call. so i dont know the exact length of data which is coming. so i need to show the daily events in the fullcalendar dynamically in a loop. the following code i tried but i didnt got the output. can anyone help me. thanx in advance

```
var testJson = ['value1', 'value2'];
$('#full_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: [
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
            {
                title: ''+testJson [i],
                start: new Date(y, m, 3)
            }
    } ]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things first:
when you want to know the exact length of the recived data.... why not send them within the JSON object?

e.g.

`var test = {"data":[1,2,3,4,5],"size":5}`

the second way to get the lentgh is the length field. Every javascript object has a length field. In the example above test.data.length would return 5 (as test.size would do).

and i'm pretty sure you can't run a iteration within a array declaration, so just build the array befor:

```
var events = [];
$(test).each(function(i, obj) {
    events[] = {title: test.data[i], start: new Date(y, m, 3)}
}
```

without jquery it would like this:

```
var size = test.data.length;
var events = [];
for(var i =0; i < size; i++) {
    events[] = {title: test.data[i], start: new Date(y, m, 3)}
}
```

and then pass it to your function call

```
$('#full_calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    editable: true,
    events: events
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use ajax call for getting data then you must write 'events: "addres for ajax request"' and add a file for ajax request. E.g. add file 'json-events.php' in the root of site, in the parametr events: 'json-events.php'. In the json-events.php you do query to the database, and get event data in array, where one event - one data array (the array in the array). Every event must have id, title, start, like:

```
array( array(
'id' => event id,
'title' => event title,
'start' => YYYY-mm-dd,
'end' => YYYY-mm-dd
))
```

After that convert to json format (json_encode()) and echo